# Error:Execution... ':app:packageRelease'.> Unable to compute hash of ..\app\build\intermediates\classes-proguard\..\release\classes.jar

Tags: java, android, android-studio, proguard

i'm trying to compile my apk with minifyEnabled true

```
 buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
}
```

i know that i need to write 'dontwarn' in 'proguard-rules.pro' file but i dont know exactly what to write
here is little part of the warnings:

```
interface javax.annotation.processing.AbstractProcessor
Warning:com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient$CountingOkHttpRequestBody: can't find superclass or interface com.squareup.okhttp.RequestBody
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.processing.AbstractProcessor
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.processing.ProcessingEnvironment
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced 
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzac: can't find referenced class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced method 'void addHeader(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)' in program class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw$zza
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw$zza: can't find referenced method 'void setURI(java.net.URI)' in program class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw$zza
Warning:com.parse.NotificationCompat$NotificationCompatImplBase: can't find referenced method 'void setLatestEventInfo(android.content.Context,java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence,android.app.PendingIntent)' in library class android.app.Notification
Warning:com.parse.ParseApacheHttpClient: can't find referenced method 'org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory getHttpSocketFactory(int,android.net.SSLSessionCache)' in library class android.net.SSLCertificateSocketFactory
Warning:com.parse.ParseApacheHttpClient: can't find referenced class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient
Warning:com.parse.ParseNotificationManager: can't find referenced method 'void setLatestEventInfo(android.content.Context,java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence,android.app.PendingIntent)' in library class android.app.Notification
Warning:com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
Warning:com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient: can't find referenced class 
Warning:com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Response
Warning:com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient$CountingOkHttpRequestBody: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.RequestBody
Warning:com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient$CountingOkHttpRequestBody: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.MediaType

Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Cache
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.CacheControl
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class 


.....
> Unable to compute hash of C:\...\classes.jar
```

Comment: I am facing with this issue aswell, somehow its deleting some constructors.

Answer (score 0):

If you are really urgently needing it built... disable minifyEnabled in the build.gradle file (minifyEnabled false). Re-enable it after.

For picasso, you can try doing:

```
-dontwarn com.squareup.picasso.**
```

etc